# iPhone app on iPad compatibility mode has strange layout in landscape (while I force portrait)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios8, uiinterfaceorientation

**The Problem**

As you can see, my iPhone app has a very strange layout when starting on iPad in landscape mode. I force the orientation of the app to portrait, but only on the iPad in landscape mode (when I start the app) seems to put the view 90 degrees turned in a portrait container. Also, the status bar seems to be a black bar and in the middle of the screen.

The app seems to work properly when I start it from portrait mode.

**When starting the app with the iPad in landscape mode**
[image: iPad compatibility mode landscape]

**When starting the app with the iPad in portrait mode**
[image: iPad compatibility mode portrait]

**My code & configuration**

The app has all 4 orientations enabled in the `info.plist` (because I dynamically switch orientation depending on which `viewController` is active).

I force the app to be portrait in the first `viewController` by using:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

I tried setting `shouldAutorotate` to `NO`, but this makes no difference.

The way I am starting my app in the `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

// 1
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = nil;
mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
// 2
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = [mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
if ([self.window respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)]) {
    self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Strangely, everything goes 100% right with testing on an iPhone. Only the iPad compatibility mode has this issue.

**Question**

How can I solve this orientation problem for the iPad compatibility mode? It seems I am missing something that only applies for the iPad compatibility mode, as nothing like this happens for the iPhone.

Comment: Firstly, you don't need to initialize the storyboard. Just make sure its in your app settings. Secondly, are you using a navigation controller?

Comment: Amazing, I fixed the problem by using the `main interface` property in the settings. Thanks alot! I had the storyboard initialization there from a long time ago to switch storyboards based on device when the iPhone 5 came out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with the help of [Ashraf Tawfeeq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3342901/ashraf-tawfeeq). I still had the code in the AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` from way back, that switched storyboard files for different devices.

I removed the corresponding code and set the `Main Interface` in my app's `info.plist` to my storyboard file.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];

if ([self.window respondsToSelector:@selector(tintColor)]) {
    self.window.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Now the app correctly turns orientation on startup on the iPad.